# jmeter :How to assign unique string generated to a variable?

Tags: jmeter

jmeter :How to assign unique string generated to a Jmeter variable?

I have generated unique string using time function and i wanted to assign it to the j meter variable,so that i can use it in the subsequent requests?

Comment: What is the code for generating code unique string in the beanshell preprocessor/JSR223 processor?

Answer (score 0):

vars.put("variablename", "youruniquestringvalue" or a string variable name);

You can access the variable in the subsequent request as
${variablename} OR vars.get("variablename")

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to generate a **unique** string I would recommend going for [__UUID() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID), it produces a [GUID structure](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID) which can be used later on.

A **random** string can be generated via [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to get familiarized with JMeter Functions concept

---

With regards to scripting approach, it should be something like:

```
vars.put('mystring', UUID.randomUUID().toString())
```

Refer generated value as `${mystring}` or `${__V(mystring)}` where required later on